# How to implement a lock in software when no hardware atomic operations are provided?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, synchronization, locking, critical-section

How to implement a lock in software when no hardware atomic operations are provided?

In [Boost.Lockfree](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/lockfree.html) documentation, they say that:

> Some architectures do not provide the necessary atomic operations in natively in hardware. If this is not the case, they are emulated in software using spinlocks.

One way I can think of is the [Dekker's algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm) which only requires non-tearing stores to work. But it only works for 2 processes. Then there is the [Peterson's algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm), which can handle N processes, but N has to be statically known. But I don't know anything that works for locking among dynamic-N processes.

Other ways that come to my mind is to disable all interrupts and context switches and power off all other cores. But these are extreme and I don't think that is done in practice.

Comment: multicore architectures have instructions for concurrency control.  Single-core architectures can momentarily disable interrupts.

Comment: Re, "...Peterson's algorithm...N has to be statically known." The number of CPUs in the system _is_ "statically known" at boot time. The OS kernel can use that to lock some static, global data that is shared across all processors. If you just have one static, global lock; you can build arbitrarily many finer-grained, and more flexible "locks" on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is make a call to the kernel, for example as described in [pthread_spin_lock](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_spin_lock.3.html).  The kernel is responsible for tracking the information across all processes.

Internally the kernel has a copy of itself running on each CPU.  You noted that Peterson's algorithm works between `N` processes, if `N` is statically known.  However inside the kernel the number of things that need to cooperate is the number of CPUs.  This the kernel **DOES** statically know, and so that's where the actual lock logic can be defined.

Comment: Any resources for further reading?

Comment: This does require kernel support. But hopefully any kernel that does preemptive multithreading does provide something like this.

Comment: It is, in fact, part of the POSIX standard: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_spin_lock.html and you can go to https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/spinlock.h and https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/locking/spinlock.c for code.